# How do I set up the NVIDIA nvcc toolchain in Netbeans 8.0 in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, netbeans, c, cuda

I found a plug-in for the nvcc toolchain but it only works on linux. What I want is to be able to compile CUDA C code on my windows computer from within Netbeans. ATM I'm using Netbeans 8 and MS Windows 8.1

(I have Visual Studio and compiling there works, but I prefer Netbeans for my Java/C++/C coding)

Bonus question: I want to compile linux CUDA C code on my windows pc (From within Netbeans for double points :D)

(by the way, because this concerns compiling, I didn't know for sure if I should post this on SU or StackOverflow. Please notify me if I should put it there)

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the plugin for NetBeans, there's a great tutorial [here](https://sites.google.com/a/nirmauni.ac.in/cudacodes/cuda-articles/article-2-netbeans-and-cuda) from the blog "Multicore and CUDA" that you should follow instead.

Also under *Code Assistance* options, make sure to also add the following macro definitions:

```
__device__
__global__
__host__
__shared__
__constant__
```

I use this all the time in NetBeans 7.4 and 8.0 to remotely compile code on a Jetson TK1 board from my Windows, Ubuntu, and Mac systems.

Comment: The problem is, I can not edit the base directory in step 2, how to work around this?

Comment: And since the tutorial is for linux, which libraries should I include? I have the Cygwin GNU compiler, the MinGW compiler and the Visual Studio compiler

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question, my apologies. The CUDA toolkit for Windows was compiled using MSVCRC, which isn't a compatible GNU compiler that NetBeans can use. Your best bet would be to download the linux distro of the CUDA toolkit and compile the source yourself in Cygwin or MinGW. Once you have that compiled library, you can include it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that for nvcc? I heard it isn't a normal compiler, because it uses other compilers to do the dirty work :P
Also, I can't find the source files